# javascript for loop function

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop

I have this index.html

```
<html>
<head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js" > </script>  
</head>
<body>
<center><h1>Images</h1></center>
<center> 
    <img id="b1" onclick="image()" src="1.jpg">
    <img id="b2" onclick="image()" src="2.jpg">
    <img id="b3" onclick="image()" src="3.jpg">    
    <img id="b4" onclick="image()" src="4.jpg">    
</center> 

</body>
</html>
```

and this scripts.js

```
function image(){

    for(var i = 1; i < document.images.length; i++)
    {
            document.write(i);
    }
```

when i click the first image it just show the number 1 on screen and the browser get stuck thinking.

why is doesnt show 123?

Comment: Note that `<center>` is obsolete in HTML5 and `document.write` is considered bad-practice. Also arrays in ECMAscript start at `0`, not `1`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your loop isn't working is because the first time you call

```
document.write
```

it's removing all of the images from the page, and thus, reducing the length of the document.images node list to zero.

If you want to see 1234, instead of using document.write (which is deprecated anyway as Dai pointed out) use:

```
document.body.innerHTML += i;
```

Also, as Dai correctly points out, the first array index is 0 not 1, so your for loop should be as follows:

```
for(var i = 0; i < document.images.length; i++)
{
        document.body.innerHTML += i;
}
```

Notice: var i = 0;

Answer (score 0):

Array indexes start at `0` in ECMAscript, not `1`, you'll need to rewrite your loop as so:

```
for(var i=0;i<document.images.length;i++) {

}
```

Note that `document.write` is now considered bad-practice as it triggers a lot of heavy-lifting in the browser's DOM and layout engines. Instead use `document.createElement`.